# How to allow hard coded strings and stop asking about using strings.xml

Tags: android, string, android-studio

I'm working currently on an android project and I have no plans in mind whatsoever to translate it to other languages, so I'm not saving string literals in strings.xml. However Android Studio keeps complaining everytime I hard code a string literal especially when setting the text value for a `TextView`.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Is there a way to disable these warnings?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you can edit it in the following location Settings->Editor->Inspections->Android Lint->TextView Internationalization:

[image: Editor]

and for the xml Settings->Editor->Inspections->Android Lint->Hardcoded Text:

[image: XML]

Comment: It removes the warnings from the java classes, how do i also remove the warnings from the layouts xml?

Comment: Perfect, they are all gone now

Comment: You saved my life!

Answer (score 7):

The best way to do this in my opinion  is to use a gradle file, this will allow you to suppress these globally without having to do it in Android Studio, so your settings can go into source control as well, and then you don't have to individually decorate each method you want to apply the warning to. To do this, disable SetTextI18n in your gradle files lint options as follows:

```
android {
    lintOptions{
        disable 'SetTextI18n'
    }
}
```

Gradle sync and voila, warnings gone.

Answer (score 5):

Add

```
@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
```

on top of your function(s).
Example:

```
@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
private void updateEZWBMode2ConnectionStatus(){
    switch (IsConnected.checkMode2(mContext)){
        case IsConnected.USB_TETHERING:
            M2StatusTV.setText("Status: Connected");
            M2StatusTV.setTextColor(Color.argb(255,0,255,0));
            M2ReceiveTV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            startTestReceiverSafe(M2ReceiveTV);
            break;
        case IsConnected.USB_CONNECTED:
            M2StatusTV.setText("Status: No Tethering");
            M2StatusTV.setTextColor(Color.argb(255,255,51,51));
            M1ReceiveTV.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            M2ReceiveTV.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            stopTestReceiverSafe();
            break;
        case IsConnected.USB_NOTHING:
            M2StatusTV.setText("Status: No USB Connection");
            M2StatusTV.setTextColor(Color.argb(255,255,51,51));
            M1ReceiveTV.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            M2ReceiveTV.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            stopTestReceiverSafe();
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*Old question, but anyway the accepted answer is misleading.*

There is no need to translate string literal resources. In fact, they can be [marked as non-translatable](http://tools.android.com/recent/non-translatablestrings) in the resources file. This way, you'll still adhere to [best practices](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2015/11/18/TheProgrammersOath.html) while not being annoyed by lint and translations.

```
<string name="invite_sent" translatable="false">Invite sent</string>
```

While disabling Lint my be useful to stop being annoyed, there is a further reason you want to (and **should**) use string literal resources: repetition. Following the DRY ([Don't Repeat Yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)) principle can avoid a miriad of problems down the line, from complex refactors to unexpected behaviour, as well as inconsistency in the user(s) experience while using the app. Just imagine that an "Ok" button is present in 10+ screens. Having a single reference and source simplifies and centralizes maintenance of the project.